# Boot hangs: A start job is running

Tags: systemd

In a virtual box I have a Debian that I sometimes want to run without X. So I edited `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` and added another menu item with a kernel option `"nox"` appended. Then I added a line to `/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service`, Section `[Unit]`:

```
ConditionKernelCommandLine=!nox
```

However, when starting this, it hangs with the message:

```
A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (56min / no limit)
```

Thank you, `systemd` for informing me about that. I wouldn't have noticed. Yet, I would like to know, *which* job it is that's hanging.

The system allows me to connect via SSH, but none of the `systemctl` or `journalctl` commands I tried did tell me the name of the service causing the problem. `lightdm.service` itself seems to be satisfied.

Comment: Thank you, pals! I'm not really surprised that Systemd doesn't even have a community that is willing to answer such a simple question. I did some research about the problem and I decided that this was definitely the last time I tried to solve a problem with Systemd.

Answer (score 3):

I known it's a but late, but I just found out that one can use:

systemctl list-jobs

to find out what units are waiting or running at any given moment.

By adding systemd.debug-shell=1 to the kernel command line, a root shell will be available on TTY9 (crlt+alt+F9) to run the command above.

I first tried "systemd-analyze", and that gave me the message about "systemctl list-jobs".

hope this helps someone with similar problems.

Comment: you're welcome! :)